# My timer loop intermittently slows down, not sure why

Tags: c#, loops, timer

I have a API request queue that I have looped using `System.Timers.Timer`. I set it up like this:

```
    private static void SetupTimerLoop()
    {
        queueLoopTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        queueLoopTimer.Interval = 100;
        queueLoopTimer.Start();
    }
```

Periodically `OnTimedEvent` will only get called once every second, almost exactly for large spans of time. It will then speed back up to once every 100ms. I cannot accurately reproduce these results, sometimes it happens, sometimes it does not. I have watched my CPU usage and it doesn't spike during these times of slowdown, if anything it goes down.

If I make breakpoints it shows that the timers interval is still only 100ms.

What could be going on here? Is there anything I can do to further troubleshoot this?

Potentially related, when this happens all my HTTP requests that are initiated from the loop (these are put onto Tasks so they return asynchronously) stop returning.

Request related:

```
    private T Get<T>(string endpoint, IRequest request) where T : class
    {
        var client = InitHttpClient();

        string debug = BaseUrl + endpoint + ToQueryString(request);

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(BaseUrl + endpoint + ToQueryString(request)).Result;
        string body = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            T result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(body, _serializerSettings);

            return result;
        }

        var error = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HelpScoutError>(body);
        throw new HelpScoutApiException(error, body);                                                                 
    }
```

I never get to: `string body = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;` as long as the loop seems to be running slow.

Not sure if that could have something to do with it, hopefully you guys have some insight.

Edit: I don't flood the API with requests. I throttle the number of requests that go out per rolling 60-second period. During that time I just use an if statement to pass over the API call for that loop.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm not too clear when you say you have a loop. Your "OnTimedEvent" is an event handler that gets triggered at a preset interval (100ms).

As for a hint, you might want to try adding logic at the beginning of your "OnTimedEvent" handler to prevent re-entrance, just in-case your "OnTimedEvent" handler is taking longer than 100ms.

```
    static int working = 0;
    private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (working > 0)
            return;

        working++;

        //do your normal work here

        working--;
    }
```

Comment: Hi YooManFoo, it is definitely an event handler that gets triggered at a preset interval. However, I am very confused as to why it sometimes does not get triggered at the appropriate time. Thank you for your suggestion, I have implemented that.

Comment: You may want to add more code snippet here so we can try it out, if you are still having problem.